# How can I avoid starting new line when using <div class=> for ajax refresh loading?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I wrap with  just like below, it automatically goes to next line.
Without  , the button comes right next to it, that's what I want.
But I have to use  for ajax reload purpose.
How can I solve this?

```
<div class="bookmark" data-communities-id="<%= community.id %>">
    <%= render :partial => "communities/bookmark", :locals => {:community => community} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a div for something you want as inline content, use a span instead.

```
<span class="bookmark" data-communities-id="<%= community.id %>">
    <%= render :partial => "communities/bookmark", :locals => {:community => community} %>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks better to me!

Answer (score 1):

Use the display:inline for bookmark class.

```
.bookmark{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block-level element. This means that it will act like a block, and not like an inline element.

Change `display` property to

- `inline` if you want to change it to an inline level element;
- `inline-block` if you want it to be inline, but to act as a block
  element level.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/

CSS

```
div {
 border: 1px solid red; 
 padding: 10px; 
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: white;
 width: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
Display: block (default):<br/><br/>
<div>Frindcode</div>
<div>Bookmark</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

Display: inline:<br/><br/>
<div style="display: inline;">Frindcode</div>
<div style="display: inline;">Bookmark</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

Display: inline-block:<br/><br/>
<div style="display: inline-block;">Frindcode</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">Bookmark</div>
```